# SQL - How to put a condition for which table is selected without left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbeaver

I have a flag in a table which value ( 1 for US, or 2 for Global) indicates if the data will be in Table A or Table B.

A solution that works is to left join both tables; however this slows down significantly the scripts (from less than a second to over 15 seconds).

Is there any other clever way to do this? an equivalent of

```
 join TableA only if TableCore.CountryFlag = "US"
 join TableB only if TableCore.CountryFlag = "global"
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Can you add DDL and sample data to your question?  It's not very clear what you are asking for currently.

Comment: Please add your script to the question

Comment: Why do you have different tables for US and Global? One common would do fine, and you'll not have this problem anymore.

Comment: write `if` and `else` , embed script within

Comment: @jarlh not my decision, I have to live with this awkward structure..  using MS SQL Server

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989593/determine-table-to-join-based-on-the-condition

Comment: If you are using SQL Server then why multiple tags

Comment: Create a view that UNION ALL's the tables. JOIN thew view.

Comment: This sounds more like a normalisation issue than anything. Although you seem to have said no, I suggest to reconsider your table design. The question isn't complete enough to make other suggestions, in my view. For example, could you have a query which needs to return data where some rows have the value `'US'` and other rows the value `'global'`, meaning you'll need to check both tables?

Comment: @PSK Thanks for the tip. It works!

Comment: @BHouse Thanks for the tip it works!

Comment: @jarlh the thing is I have this situation with 4 tables and my script is already 2 A4 pages; creating unions would make it 4 times bigger! the IF ELSE solution works

Comment: I said UNION ALL to emulate a correct db design. Handy view anyway.

Comment: @Larnu I am 100% with you on the table design point. I have no control over that unfortunately.

Comment: @jarlh that's a very good idea; the only problem is there are many cases where the same primary key is used in both the tables for different entries. so awesome idea just not for my case unfortunately

Comment: Sorry @jarlh, I honestly though you'd omitted the `ALL`. Must have missed it. :)

Comment: @YoussefE even if you have no control, it might be worth feeding back to whoever does; if you don't then it's never going to change and your developer is going to continue to make poor design choices.

Comment: @Larnu oh I did pass on angry comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this approach:

```
-- US data
SELECT
    YourColumns
FROM
    TableCore
    INNER JOIN TableA AS T ON TableCore.JoinColumn = T.JoinColumn
WHERE
    TableCore.CountryFlag = 'US'

UNION ALL

-- Non-US Data
SELECT
    YourColumns -- These columns must match in number and datatype with previous SELECT
FROM
    TableCore
    INNER JOIN TableB AS T ON TableCore.JoinColumn = T.JoinColumn
WHERE
    TableCore.CountryFlag = 'global'
```

However, if the result is still slow, you might want to check if the TableCore table has a index on CountryFlag and JoinColumn, and TableA and TableB an index on JoinColumn.

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure is:

```
select . . ., coalesce(a.?, b.?) as ?
from tablecore c left join
     tablea a
     on c.? = a.? and c.countryflag = 'US' left join
     tableb b
     on c.? b.? and c.counryflag = 'global';
```

This version of the query can take advantage of indexes on `tablea(?)` and `tableb(?)`.

If you have a complex query, this portion is probably not responsible for the performance problem.